# android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to start a Fragment inside my RecycleAdapter but when cast my Context with the AppCompatActivity the App crashed and inside logcat I got the message that android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.

here is my onClickListener inside RecycleAdapter.

```
holder.ItemClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            Toast.makeText(CTX,"Row Clicked id : "+homeCycleDataProvider.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ItemsFragment fragobj = new ItemsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) CTX).getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragobj);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

here is my Adapter Initialization where I pass the context.

```
adapter = new ItemsRecycleAdapter(arrayList,getContext());
```

LOGCAT.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.a1appstudio.sabirhossain.xpresdelivery, PID: 3109
              java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
                  at com.a1appstudio.sabirhossain.xpresdelivery.ItemsListViewPackage.ItemsRecycleAdapter$1.onClick(ItemsRecycleAdapter.java:66)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A context is not always an Activity, even when you're in an Activity.  It could be an Application, or a wrapper around another context.  It's almost always wrong to cast a Context to an Activity.  If you absolutely need one, you should pass in an Activity as a parameter, rather than a Context.  Or better yet, pass in the support fragment manager directly rather than the activity, since that's all you need it for.

Comment: you are right, it's better to pass FragmentManager.. thanks.

Comment: makes perfect sense, and solved my issue of calling fragmentmanager from custom adapter for me! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter = new ItemsRecycleAdapter(arrayList,getActivity());
```

you can try this

```
if (context instanceof MainActivity ) {

    MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity)context;

    myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Comment: santosh kumar thanks for your answer, but also tried with this getActivity() but the result is same.

Comment: instead of AppCompatActivity you can try using activity name

Comment: something like (MainActivity) CTX